# CAShapeLayer + UIBezierPath fill animation is unfilling shape instead of filling?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

i have a heart-shaped uibezierpath and have been using CAShapeLayers to mask and a CABasicAnimation of bounds.height to fill with it red color from the bottom.  i have obviously gotten something key mixed up since the shape appears as filled with red and then gets cleared out from the bottom! Gah! This animation is triggered by a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, fyi. Can anyone tell me where i am screwing it up? here is the code:

```
        var filledShape = CAShapeLayer()
        filledShape.bounds = bezierPath.bounds
        filledShape.path = bezierPath.CGPath
        filledShape.fillColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        var outlineShape = CAShapeLayer()
        outlineShape.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(bezierPath.bounds, nil)
        outlineShape.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
        outlineShape.lineWidth = 1.5

        var inPlaceOutlineShape = CAShapeLayer()
        inPlaceOutlineShape.bounds = filledShape.bounds
        inPlaceOutlineShape.path = filledShape.path

        inPlaceOutlineShape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        inPlaceOutlineShape.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        inPlaceOutlineShape.opaque=false
        inPlaceOutlineShape.lineWidth = 1.5

        filledShape.mask=outlineShape

        var heartRect = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x,self.view.center.y, bezbox.width+1, bezbox.height+1)

        var animateOutlineFromBottom = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")
        animateOutlineFromBottom.fromValue=0
        animateOutlineFromBottom.toValue=bezbox.height
        animateOutlineFromBottom.duration=3.0
        animateOutlineFromBottom.fillMode=kCAFillModeForwards
        //animateOutlineFromBottom.

        bgview.frame = heartRect

        bgview.layer.addSublayer(filledShape)

        bgview.layer.addSublayer(inPlaceOutlineShape)

        self.view.addSubview(bgview)

        outlineShape.addAnimation(animateOutlineFromBottom, forKey:"bounds.size.height")
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are animating the mask from 0 to a finite height. Instead change the position of the mask from bottom to top position.

```
var animateOutlineFromBottom = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animateOutlineFromBottom.fromValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(0, heartRect.height))
animateOutlineFromBottom.toValue = NSValue(CGPoint: CGPointMake(0,0))
animateOutlineFromBottom.duration = 3.0
animateOutlineFromBottom.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards

 // Other code

outlineShape.addAnimation(animateOutlineFromBottom, forKey:"position")
```